# Function access in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to access functions through inheritance without setting function access to public?

For example: I have Foo.cfc and it extends Bar.cfc. If I want to call a Bar.cfc function from Foo.cfc, I have to set the function access to public.

If I set the function access to private, then it's only accessible from Foo.cfc. Is there no "intermediate" access level that is not quite public but not strictly private? i.e. it allows access through inheritance only...

Comment: I made a mistake. It turns out private methods are accessible as Henry and others pointed out. Sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the keyword `super`? Because [private methods should be available to sub components](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/buildingComponents_33.html) like Foo.cfc.

**Foo.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent extends="Bar">
    .....
    <cffunction name="fooMethod" access="public" ...>
         <cfreturn super.nameOfAMethodInBarCFC() />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: don't even need "super" unless "nameOfAMethodInBarCFC" exists in Bar as well.

Comment: True. I always use it though. Then there is never a conflict. Just personal preference.

Answer (score 5):

> If I set the function access to private, then it's only accessible from Foo.cfc

**NOT TRUE!**  `private` access level in ColdFusion is same as `protected` in Java, so you can still call that private method of Bar from Foo

Comment: Yes, similar. But not *the same*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the access property in cffunction to package.  That will allow it to be accessed by any component that extends the component.

Comment: Package level access is not necessary. Private methods are available to sub components.